# errors coming after installing Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit from a usb stick

Tags: usb, 64-bit

I keep getting errors after the installation of Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit installed using a USB stick. The first time this happened was yesterday when I tried to upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04, but when I connected my DSL internet with the newly upgraded Ubuntu 15.04 I received the `network path can't find` error message.

After that I decided to format my whole Hard Disk Drive using the disks application and install Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit again, however after I downloaded `skype`, `maxthon`, `gdebi`, `git`, plus many more software packages and restarted my computer the system hung at shutdown so I hit the restart button and the window with the error check options comes up. Why are these error happening?

Answer (score 1):

Powering off a running Ubuntu (or Windows or any PC) with the power switch or reset button can often lead to corrupted filesystems, OS's, and data loss, it's a terrible habit.

On Linux you can often use the "Magic SysRq" codes, like REISUB, to have the kernel more safely reboot a misbehaving system.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/safe-reboot-of-linux-using-magic-sysrq-key/

You use them by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd>
Or maybe <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd>
Or possibly including the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key on laptops, it can get complicated so practice to see what works for yours before needing it

That's if they've been enabled, sometimes they're not by default. This enables them:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

---

I don't know about the earlier `network path can't find` error, maybe googling it could have found a solution, or maybe the upgrade just didn't work, doing a fresh install of the version you want should be more reliable than trying an upgrade from an old version.

Comment: thanks,,so i will never upgrade ubuntu again...i hit restart button after 20 maybe 30 minutes....before my hitting to restart button ,,when i see by  pressing ESC button,,terminal window showing.stopping something starting something.. i dont know why..